# how to invoke servlet from the client code in gwt 

Tags: java

66305
HI,
    I want to invoke a Servlet from the client side, as a Onclick event on a Button in java programming language.
    I read somewhere through anchor tag we can call a servlet, but i did not figure out the solution or Syntax properly.

Anyone please me.

Thanks,
sekhar

Answer (score 1):

Typically you use a `RemoteService` to communicate with a server. To do that, you create an interface that extends `RemoteService` and an implementation on the server that implements that interface and extends `RemoteServiceServlet`. All that is described in more detail [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html). If you need to make a call to some servlet that isn't a remote service servlet, you can use `RequestBuilder` to send an HTTP request to that servlet's URL.

An `Anchor` is basically just a normal HTML `<a>` tag which could link to the URL of a servlet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually create one httpClient & call GET/POST method.

Below is sample code using POST method:

```
//---

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    BufferedReader br = null;

    PostMethod method = new PostMethod("http://someUrl.com");
    method.addParameter("p", "\"parameter\"");

    int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

    if(statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) {
         System.out.println("Not Supported");
         method.getResponseBodyAsString();
    } else {
         br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
         String readLine;
         while(((readLine = br.readLine()) != null)) {
              System.out.println(readLine);
          }
    }

//---
```